# How do I change my web config file to use MySQL and completely ignore SQL Express or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, web.config-transform

This is my current web.config file in my connection strings you will see two connections default and vsmh. I tried to remove the default connection with SQL Exress, but then it says my Account model is using it to validate authentication which doesn't make much sense:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
    -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings> 
        <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-VanguardApp-20140610090811;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-VanguardApp-20140610090811.mdf" />
        <add name="vsmhEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.vsmh.csdl|res://*/Models.vsmh.ssdl|res://*/Models.vsmh.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=vanguardpl;database=vsmh&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <clear />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version= 6.5.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /><add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5"><assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /></assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".cshtml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" /> 
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <!--
                        If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
                        you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
                        change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
                        of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
            -->
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Windows.Data" publicKeyToken="5803CFA389C90CE7" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2014.2.729.45" newVersion="2014.2.729.45" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Windows.Controls" publicKeyToken="5803CFA389C90CE7" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2014.2.729.45" newVersion="2014.2.729.45" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.7.5.0" newVersion="6.7.5.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think it's referring to the fact your membership, role, and profile providers all make use of the sql express db.

Comment: The problem is that your default connection uses the SQLClient which means the code in your app uses the SQLCLient. You cannot just change your config and think it will change all your code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Asp.Net Membership provider is using SQL Express with a separate db context. You need to either set mysql connection string in DefaultConnection or change your account db context to use vsmhEntities connection string. Even after this you need make sure all membership tables are created in your mysql database so the membership provider can find it.

You can also check the below link to see how to use MySql for membership database:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html